# Parse large amounts of JSON data in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I am looking for an efficient way - in terms of memory as well as speed -  to parse large amount of JSON data (in order of several hundreds of MB) in python.

I looked at ijson package: https://pypi.org/project/ijson/ and experimented with its parse function but the for loop event parser appears to be very slow if I were to parse something at middle or bottom of JSON.

Below is the sample of similar json structure I have. JSON representing data of several hundreds of websites so data.items.website can grow very large and so does data.items.ids. With that kind of large structure - I found ijson event parser for loop to be very slow if I were to get information on some data in the middle or bottom of the data.items.website or data.items.ids.

```
{
    "data": {
        "items": {
                "website": [
                    [
                        "abc.com",
                        [
                            [
                                "data1",
                                {
                                    "type1": 10,
                                    "type2": 11
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                "data2",
                                {
                                    "type1": 100,
                                    "type2": 150
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                "data3",
                                {
                                    "type1": 40,
                                    "type2": 50
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                 ]
        },
            "ids": [
                [
                    "id1",
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "id2",
                    2
                ]
             ]
       }
}
```

```
for prefix, event, value in parser:
    if prefix.startswith('data.items.ids'):
        print(f"prefix {prefix}, event {event}, value {value}")
```

I am not sure if I am using ijson correctly or in a best way to to reap its benefits such that gives me speed as well as at the same time keeps memory consumption low to parse from large amounts of JSON.

Could someone help?

Comment: share a bit of the data u r working with, folks can test it and see where the bottlenecks might be. if it is a url, u could share that as well. also, share what you have tried with ijson (ur code could be helpful)

Comment: Thanks, added sample json structure and some code I tried with.

Comment: great. kindly add ur expected output as well.

Comment: I think I need a faster way to get a particular prefix while keeping memory consumption low. I tried with ijson.items(data.items.website) and json.items(data.items.ids) but as you can imagine with several hundreds of website data that structure could potentially be quite large increasing the memory usage.

Comment: hard to say without a benchmark ... i'll give it a go , hopefully others can take a crack at it

Comment: may i suggest, if u can, step outside of python and unto the command line : [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). takes some getting used to, but it is very powerful and even handles streaming. also have a look at [jello](https://blog.kellybrazil.com/2020/03/25/jello-the-jq-alternative-for-pythonistas/) - it does require u to work on the command line. u should get faster speeds and more efficient processing on the command line with either of these tools

Comment: Yes, I have used jq on a command line; but was looking something that has python bindings to use in a code.

Comment: Note that there is no `ids` in `items`